# Count using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

With this data frame:

```
df = data.frame(mes = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                ano = c(1981, 1982,1983), 
                x1 = c(95,8,10,NA,NA,98), 
                x2 = c(NA, NA, 89, 48, NA, 10))
> df
  mes  ano x1 x2
1   1 1981 95 NA
2   1 1982  8 NA
3   2 1983 10 89
4   2 1981 NA 48
5   3 1982 NA NA
6   3 1983 98 10
```

I want to get this:

```
  mes x1_n x2_n
1   1    2    0
2   2    1    2
3   3    1    1
```

I mean, for each `mes` unique value I want to know how many non `NA` values there are. I was trying to work with `dplyr::count()` but I get this:

```
> count(df,mes)
# A tibble: 3 × 2
    mes     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     2
2     2     2
3     3     2
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: The base R equivalent with `aggregate` could be `aggregate(cbind(x1, x2)~mes, df, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), na.action = na.pass)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`count` gives you the number of observations. If you are interested in the number of observations that are not NA you can do:

```
 df %>%
   group_by(mes) %>%
   summarize(x1_n = sum(!is.na(x1)),
             x2_n = sum(!is.na(x2)))
```

Comment: And to simplify the multiple `summarize` statements, you could do `summarize_at(vars(x1,x2), function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) )`

Comment: Great! But what if I have many columns? df was just an example. I am currently working with a 360 x 125 data frame.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(mes) %>%  summarise_all(function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))`